# To change the "defaultMessage" field in your JSON file to other language based on the translations provided in an Excel file

Tags: json

Let's say I have Japanese JSON file like below.

```
[
  {
    "id": "account-setting/edit-account-information",
    "defaultMessage": "カード情報の編集",
    "translatedFrom": "Edit account information",
    "apiTranslation": false
  },
  {
    "id": "active-bookings/active-bookings-title",
    "defaultMessage": "予約一覧",
    "translatedFrom": "Active Bookings",
    "apiTranslation": false
  },
  {
    "id": "active-bookings/view-all",
    "defaultMessage": "すべて見る",
    "translatedFrom": "View All",
    "apiTranslation": true
  },
]
```

Based on this Excel file which contains translated text based on  "translatedFrom".
[image]

Using this Excel file, I want to replace Japanese with Hindi like below.

```
[
  {
    "id": "account-setting/edit-account-information",
    "defaultMessage": "खाता जानकारी संपादित(एडिट) करें",
    "translatedFrom": "Edit account information",
    "apiTranslation": false
  },
  {
    "id": "active-bookings/active-bookings-title",
    "defaultMessage": "सक्रिय बुकिंगें",
    "translatedFrom": "Active Bookings",
    "apiTranslation": false
  },
  {
    "id": "active-bookings/view-all",
    "defaultMessage": "सभी देखें",
    "translatedFrom": "View All",
    "apiTranslation": true
  },
]
```